# Jquery datepicker close

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-events

I am interested in using this weekpicker from http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/. I can not get the datepicker to close after selecting a week which I thought was default behaviour. Any suggestions?

```
$(function() {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    
    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }
    
    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
            
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });
    
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `$(this).hide();` at the end of your `onSelect` function. However, you would probably want to also provide an option for someone to open it again if they wanted to change the week.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AVZJh/1515/

Comment: Ive tried adding hide in the select, but this gets fired before the dates are updated in the HTML

Comment: Ye I just checked, I will try in my project.

Comment: I was using a mousedown event to fire the hide which was probably why.

Comment: Glad it's doing what you wanted. Happy coding.